# Removing a vector element of object type using an iterator c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, object, vector, erase

I am trying to write a function that removes a vector element from listAccounts depending on the account_name of that vector element. I have written this:

```
void Account::remove_account(string name) {

    auto iter = listAccounts.begin();

    for ( ; iter !=  listAccounts.end(); iter++) {
        if ((*iter).account_name == name) {
            listAccounts.erase(iter);
        }
    }

}
```

But I am getting a Segmentation fault from the vector removal, from what I understand it means that I tried to access memory that I do not have access to, but i'm not sure how to correctly write this.

Comment: Do you want to remove only one element or all elements with the given value?

Comment: The duplicate explains that your for-loop becomes invalid after the first erase. You need a `break;` in the if statement.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow Just one element in the vector that has account.name equal to name.

Comment: @Captain Giraffe I see, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Once you erase the element pointed to by an iterator, that iterator becomes invalid. (for a `std::vector`, all other iterators after the erased element becomes invalid too). And *incrementing* or *dereferencing* an invalid iterator has undefined behavior.

You could do (assuming only one element is to be removed):

```
void Account::remove_account(string name) {
    auto iter = std::find_if(listAccounts.begin(), listAccounts.end(), 
                 [&](const auto& s){ return s.account_name == name; });
    if(iter != listAccounts.end())
        listAccounts.erase(iter);  
}
```

For multiple elements, that will be:

```
void Account::remove_account(string name) {
    for(auto iter = listAccounts.begin(); iter != listAccounts.end(); ){
        iter = std::find_if(iter, listAccounts.end(),
                    [&](const auto& s){ return s.account_name == name; });
        if(iter != listAccounts.end())
            iter = listAccounts.erase(iter);  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If container is modified iterator becomes invalid.
There are two good solutions:

```
void Account::remove_account(const string& name) {
    auto iter = listAccounts.begin();

    while iter !=  listAccounts.end()) {
        if (iter->account_name == name) {
            iter = listAccounts.erase(iter);
        } else {
            ++iter;
        }
    }
}

// or
void Account::remove_account(const string& name) {
    listAccounts.erase(
        std::remove_if(std::begin(listAccounts), std::end(listAccounts),
                       [&name](const auto& item) {
                           return item.account_name == name;
                       }),
        std::end(listAccounts));
}
```

Comment: In the second solution you call `remove` on the vector. I think you've meant `erase`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to remove just one element then you can write

```
bool Account::remove_account( std::string &name ) 
{
    auto it = std::find_if( listAccounts.begin(),
                            listAccounts.end(),
                            [&]( const auto &item )
                            {
                                return item.account_name == name;
                            } );

    bool success = it != listAccounts.end();

    if ( success ) listAccounts.erase( it );

    return success;
}
```

As for your code then after this statement

```
listAccounts.erase(iter);
```

the iterator becomes invalid. So you may not increment it.